# AngularJS - Json with LocalStorage doesn't update Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, local-storage

I have a form in a View that should update the "color" property of an Array. This Array `colors` has 5 objects, each serving to set the color of an element of another View (so the option to use localStorage, since I can not use any access to the server, like $http).

The form view (settings.html)

```
  <form name="colorform" class="row col-md-offset-1" ng-submit="update(key)">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Color A (Tiles)</label>
              <input name="main" ng-model="colors[0].color" class="form-control">    
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Color B (Blocked Tiles)</label>
              <input name="locker" ng-model="colors[1].color" class="form-control">    
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Color C (Path)</label>
              <input name="path" ng-model="colors[2].color" class="form-control">    
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Color D (Start Point)</label>
              <input name="path" ng-model="colors[3].color" class="form-control">    
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Color E (End Point)</label>
              <input name="path" ng-model="colors[4].color" class="form-control">    
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              Update
          </button>
          <a href="#/" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
          <hr>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Excerpt from BoardController.js (which should store the update in the localStorage and update the Array colors then):

```
//Array to be updated
$scope.colors = [
    {name: "main", color: "white"},
    {name: "locker", color: "black"},
    {name: "path", color: "yellow"}, 
    {name: "start", color: "green"},
    {name: "end", color: "blue"},
];

//localStorage

$scope.update = function (key) {
    localStorage.setItem( 'colors', angular.toJson( $scope.colors, '[]' ) );
    console.log(JSON);

    var newColors = angular.fromJson( localStorage.getItem( 'colors' ) );
    for (var i = 0; i < newColors.length; i++) {
        $scope.colors == $scope.colors;
        $scope.colors = newColors[i];

        console.log($scope.colors);
    }
}
/*function that applies the style in the elements of the view main.html
  It needs to use $scope.status[$index] since Array indexes
  are the same as the status variable (not shown in this code), which 
  defines the status of each element
*/
$scope.style = function ($index) {       
    return {
        "height" : tileHeight + 'px',
        "width" : tileWidth + 'px',
        "border" : "1px solid #CCC",
        "background-color": $scope.colors[$scope.status[$index]].color,
        "float": "left"
    }
}
```

And in main.html, using the ng-style:

```
<div ng-repeat="tile in getNumber(tiles) track by $index" 
     ng-click="changeToggle($index)" ng-init="initToggle($index)" 
     ng-model="status[$index]" ng-style="style($index)"></div>
</div>
```

The data is being stored correctly, as it shows the image of the localStorage below (note that the first record has been updated to "gray" by the form):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

However, I can't update the array with the localStorage, and consequently change the colors of View main.html. What is wrong?

**EDIT 1:**

I try to change the update function, like this:

```
$scope.update = function (key) {
    localStorage.setItem( 'colors', angular.toJson( $scope.colors, [] ) );
    var newColors = angular.fromJson( localStorage.getItem( 'colors' ) );
    console.log(newColors);
    $scope.colors = newColors.slice(0);
    console.log($scope.colors);
    // for (var i = 0; i < newColors.length; i++) {
    //     $scope.colors.push(newColors);
    //     console.log(newColors);
    // }

}
```

I commented the loop, and now both Arrays have the same values in console. But I can't update yet... Maybe is the problem in the `$scope.style` function?

**EDIT 2:**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0be65ys/4/)

**EDIT 3**

Question: What if I do another structure, where each View would have its own Controller, and a Service to get and set all data between them? Is it feasible?

Comment: provide a jsfiddle please

Comment: Inside your for loop, you are reassigning `$scope.colors` to a single element of `newColors`

Comment: @inorganik What should I do instead? The idea is to assign the `newColors` values into the `$scope.colors` array, no?

Comment: @Disfigure I am trying...

Comment: Think you meant to do `$scope.colors[i] = newColors[i];`

Comment: Yes, I also tried this. But everything that I did so far (include my EDIT 1 now) has the same final result: the main.html view doesn't update...

Comment: Does your $scope.style have the updated colors?

Comment: I think ng-style needs an expression. Could you try :                      ng-style="{{style($index)}}"

Comment: @Vijay Menon my $scope.style always uses an index to assign the background-color, no matter what the color in the `$scope.colors` array. Although the use of expressions makes sense, it did not work ...

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or plunker? All these suggestions are based on looking at the code. We would be able to help you better with the complete code.

Comment: I have created a JSFiddle putting the entire code, but the results will not reflect the same situation. Please, see above at EDIT 2.

Answer (score 0):

The update function logic was wrong. In fact, when the user clicks on "Update" button, the localStorage data should be updated (or created), with the new colors. But the `localStorage.getItem` and `for loop` don't belong to the update action!

So, for the purpose of this need, the code that worked was only write the `localStorage.getItem` and `for loop` outside of the `$scope.update` function, like this:

```
$scope.update = function () {
    localStorage.setItem( 'colors', angular.toJson( $scope.colors, '[]' ) ); 
};

var newColors = angular.fromJson( localStorage.getItem( 'colors' ) );
for (var i = 0; i < newColors.length; i++) {
    $scope.colors[i] = newColors[i];
}
```